# Reading attribute values of varying layers in QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I work on a graphical model in QGIS (3.16) were I have to use attribute-information of the input layers without actually joining their attribute tables.

In the field-calculator outside the graphical modeler the attribute value of a chosen object on any layer can be directly adressed as follows: `attribute(get_feature_by_id('Layername', feature-ID), 'field_name')`.

When I put this expression into the field-calculator inside the model, it does work, as long as I use the "fixed/unique"-layer name which can be selected in the layer-tab of expresssion-dialogue. As I want this to be flexible however, I thought of choosing a variable (e.g. @input_layer1 from the model) as layer-name. This results in a non-specific "SyntaxError invalid syntax (, line 1)"-> A problem with resolving the variable, but how to do it/which alternative variable/approach to choose?